# white space is displaying after we added tabs in page

Tags: html, css, magento

before we are displaying 2 kinds of information in [site1](http://stylebaby.com/retro-scooter-with-helmet-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) one below the other.

1)Product Description  2)Packaging

[image]

[image]

now we are displaying information in [site2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) as **tabs**. after we displaying as tabs. Its not displaying information in full width, you can see **white space displaying in right side of information.**

I want to remove those white space and display as in site1 once we click on tabs.

[image]

[image]

```
.tabs{
        display:inline-block;
        width:250px;
        height:45px;
        line-height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:orange;
        color:white;
        font-size:19px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .tabs.active{
        cursor:default;
    }
    .tabs.active:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tab-text{
        display:none;
        width:90%;
        height:auto;
        padding:5%;
    }
    .tab-text.active{
        display:block;
    }
```

**phtml**

```
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        <div class="next-content-product">

<h1>Product Description </h1>
<?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>

<div class="size-space">
<h1>Product Size & Space <span class="hidden-sku"><?php echo $_product->getSku();?></span> </h1>


<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('size_space');?>
</div>


</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        <div class="next-level-content-product">
<div class="interior-exterior">

<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('interior_exterior');?>

</div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below css

```
.tab-text{
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
 }
```

Comment: i tried your solution, one line is displaying at the end and bottom, can you please help me to remove that and make it as like other site.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the `width: 90%` from .tab-text, this is basically the reason of your problem

Comment: i tried your solution, one line is displaying at the end and bottom, can you please help me to remove that and make it as like other site

Answer (score 1):

```
.tab-text.active {
    display: initial;
}
```

use this for full display.